# Elasticsearch on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, elasticsearch, windows-server-2012-r2

I've spent some time now looking for information regarding elasticsearch.yml configurations that make my single instance Elasticsearch (on Windows 2012 Server EC2) accessible via public ip, but everytime I uncomment one or both of following settings the only thing that changes is, calling the private ip as well results in an error.

```
network.publish_host: <public ip>

network.bind_host: <private ip>
```

Is this correct and are there any other settings that have to be defined? Shouldn't it run with the default values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a general answer as to how networking works within EC2 instead of a specific answer to your question. But it should help inform how to configure your application.

EC2 has 1:1 NAT between a public and private IP address. Because of this, only the private IP address is visible to the instance directly.

If you are binding a service to a network interface, it would be the one with the private IP.

Some services do require knowledge of the external IP address in order to function properly. The only one I have run into is FTP in a passive configuration, likely due to the fact that it needs to open a separate socket for data transfer.

In the case of elastic search, it appears that they have a special plugin that will help configure elastic search for the aws environment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

Comment: Would you mind sharing the elastic search configuration? Thanks!

Comment: in addition to the plugin, this [config example](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/node-discovery-in-elasticsearch-on-amazon-ec2/36490/17) helped me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Installed only one instance of ES on aws EC2 and wanted to grant it public access.

On ubuntu 16.04 this is what works for me:

in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml add this line:

`network.host: <ec2 instance private ip>`

The private ip should be something like 172.x.x.x

Also do not forget allow access in security group in your aws console for port 9200 (default) and ip address from which you will be sending requests.

So difference was setting not public but private ip address from aws console..

**Also note that this can be dangerous as there is not any user/password or other access control**